# Cannot share a view into mutiple component

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a task that need to share camera view from a webcam into 2 Window. I've tried using singleton for create camera view only one time. The problem is that created instance can not share between 2 class. I'm now really confused. What am I doing wrong here?

MainWindow class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReceptionMainWindow receptionMainWindow = new ReceptionMainWindow();
        CustomerMainWindow customerMainWindow = new CustomerMainWindow();
        receptionMainWindow.Show();
        customerMainWindow.Show();

        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Receptionist class

```
    public partial class ReceptionMainWindow : Window
{
    public ReceptionMainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReceptionWindowHoler.Content = CameraPage.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Customer Class

```
    public partial class CustomerMainWindow : Window
{
    public CustomerMainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CustomerWindowHoler.Content = CameraPage.getInstance();
    }
}
        private static CameraPage instance;
```

Camera class

```
public CameraPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //DataContext = CameraViewModel.getInstance();
        this.DataContext = this;
        GetVideoDevices();
    }
    public static CameraPage getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new CameraPage();
        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need singleton ? In WPF FrameworkElements can only have one logical parent. The same instance cannot be assigned to two different controls. You need to create another instance of the CameraPage. Just remove the Singleton and assign your camera page like: .Content = new CameraPage();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Bitmap from the camera view and share it via events to the two other windows.

Take this answer as a workaround. There must be a better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use MainWindow for root BitmapImage, then I share Camera Bitmap thoughtout CameraViewModel (Using Singleton) -> It works :>>